# Android : Invoke the Alert dialog on any visible activity from helper class?

Tags: android, alert

i have the following problem.

I trying to invoke the alert dialog  from simple helper class

```
public class NotificationHelper
```

Because the code is not executed on the activity but after the receiving push notification and if activity is running on the foreground.

So i tried to do it by this way:

```
// Show dialog
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    final String finalNotificationHeading = notificationHeading;
                    final String finalNotificationBody = notificationBody;

                    handler.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    DialogHelper.showSimpleAlert(finalNotificationHeading, finalNotificationBody, ctx.getString(R.string.positive_button_text),
                                            ctx.getString(R.string.negative_button_text), null, ctx, notificationAlertCallback);
                                }
                            }
                    );
```

But i always getting the following error:

```
com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$DialogException: Bad window token, you cannot show a dialog before an Activity is created or after it's hidden.
```

Note: Error is not caused by the plugin.

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: From where do you invoke this code? From the activity that is receiving the notification?

Comment: No, from the notificationHelper which is called from push notification service.

Comment: You need an activity of your application in foreground to display the dialog. Without that, it won't display it.

Comment: App si in foreground, so some activity is displayed. I am able to get which activity is running. But how can i get his context? Should i have some singleton instance? Could You please provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is ctx. And the moment you are passing it.

It should be given at the moment you are want to create a dialog, and it should current UI (activity, fragment etc)

```
Bad window token
```

Says that context that you are trying to add dialog is not currently on the screen.

So you method should look like

```
NotificationHelper{
void showDialog(Activity currentActivity){
          Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    final String finalNotificationHeading = notificationHeading;
                    final String finalNotificationBody = notificationBody;

                    handler.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    DialogHelper.showSimpleAlert(finalNotificationHeading, finalNotificationBody, currentActivity.getString(R.string.positive_button_text),
                                            currentActivity.getString(R.string.negative_button_text), null, currentActivity, notificationAlertCallback);
                                }
                            }
                    );

}
```

If you dont wanna pass currentActivity all the time when calling showDialog you should pass your currentContext in onResume of every Activity that you want to use it in

```
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  NotificationHelper.ctx = this;
}
```

and use it like in your case, but you must be aware that if you pass wrong context (or not do it at all) Bad window token exception may occure.